# DTrace - How do I correctly retrieve initial parameters in the return probe

Tags: dtrace

I'm trying to read the initial arguments that was passed into the function in my return probe. Unlike the entry probe, the argument variables(`arg0`,`arg1`,...) in the return probe do not contain the initial parameters, and I'm not sure how I would be able to retrieve those values.

Also, I would like to avoid storing the values in global variables because of the concurrency issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the parameters in thread-local storage, e.g.

```
pid$target:foo:bar:entry
{
    self->arg0 = arg0;
    self->arg1 = arg1;
    /*
     * Avoid the race in which dtrace(1) attaches to the victim during
     * the window between the two probes.
     */
    self->trace = 1;
}

pid$target:foo:bar:return
/self->trace/
{
    printf("arg0 = 0x%x, arg1 = 0x%x\n", self->arg0, self->arg1);
    /* Deallocate the thread-local storage. */
    self->arg0 = 0;
    self->arg1 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As rmh answered - using local variables is the way to do it. Otherwise, dtrace would have to save the values for you on entry - and it doesnt know anything about the incoming arguments or your expectations, and would have to garbage collect. (Technically, it does know whats going to happen - eventually - but that would add complex overhead vs the local variables approach which is mapped to a simple set of virtual D instructions).